# Why is checkbox with jQuery is not working?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Neither `.prop('checked')` nor `.is(':checked')` is working.

```
if($("#isAgeSelected").is(':checked')){
   $("#txtAge").show();
}else{
   $("#txtAge").hide();
}
```

Html is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected"/>
<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">Age is something</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/5938/)

Comment: You don't listen to the `change` event!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/5941/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to `change` event:

```
$("#isAgeSelected").change(function(){
  if($("#isAgeSelected").is(':checked')){
     $("#txtAge").show();
  }else{
     $("#txtAge").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated Code check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sDsCM/18/)

#### HTML

```
 <input class="isAgeSelected" type="checkbox" name="isAgeSelected" value="1" />
<div id="txtAge">Age is something</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$("#txtAge").hide();
$(".isAgeSelected").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#txtAge").show();
    } else {
        $("#txtAge").hide();
    }
});
```